# ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged and Mysql Fatal Error

Tags: c#, mysql, select, combobox

I am currently having an issue with a dual combobox selection query... After the 1st combo box value is selected, it sends that value to the database and causes the 2nd combo box to populate. However I am getting a fatal error in the exception from the database when selecting from the 1st combobox. If I run a query not involving the 1st combobox, it runs fine.

Here is my code, I've been toying with the query line... So I wouldn't be surprised if it's wrong.

```
private void cmbDepartment_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;database=mydatabase;uid=admin;Pwd=mypw1234;");

                string selectQuery = "SELECT `name` FROM `employees` WHERE `department` LIKE ?department";
                connection.Open();
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?department",cmbDepartment.Text);
                    cmbName.Items.Add(reader.GetString("name"));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

the exception says "Fatal error encountered during command execution"
Can some1 explain what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**
When I run this It says I have an issue in my syntax near "Projects" Which the name is "Special Projects"... But If I run the straight Query with "Special Projects" it works fine...

```
string selectQuery = "SELECT `name` FROM `employees` WHERE `department` = " + cmbDepartment.Text + "";
```

Comment: Any idea what the error might be?

Comment: Set the parameter before you execute the command.

Comment: the ex says "Fatal error encountered during command execution"

Comment: if you want to improve your application, - the way you are filling the second combo box is unefficient, all of that multiple  calls to the database consumes a lot of resources. a better practice is to set a `datatable` with all the information from database and than query the datatable with `LINQ` or event with loops (if there are not a lot of records) on every time that combobox1 value is changed.

Comment: @jonathana if the user never chooses anything from the combobox, you loaded all the items for no reason. Also what if there are a million rows or event more, you want to load all of them into a datatable? That is not a good suggestion.

Comment: I'm trying to select an item from the 1st combo box that was populated from the database to pull information from a separate table. Which it is pulling information. But something is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep creating the parameter every time the reader reads a row:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?department", cmbDepartment.Text);
    cmbName.Items.Add(reader.GetString("name"));
}
```

What is worse is you are not passing it before you you execute your command so your command does not have the `department` parameter.

Your code should be like this:

```
// add the parameter first
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?department", cmbDepartment.Text);

// Now execute the command. Now it has the parameter
MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

// Now populate your combo box
while (reader.Read())
{
    cmbName.Items.Add(reader.GetString("name"));
}
```

Comment: I see... sigh... Once I think I got something down, I make mistakes like this... Works Like a charm. Noted :) Thanks

Comment: Can you the same execution with the Command builder and Data adapter to fill a datagrid?

Comment: You can use anything you want. It just needs data and it doesn't care how you get the data. Even if you get the data from a web service, it will work.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured out how to do it :)